# How to pass a list of options to the back-end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a list of items on a razor page which can be updated by user on front-end with javascript:

```html
<select asp-for="Answers" asp-items="Model.Answers" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

I also have a bind property for this list:

```cs
[BindProperty]
public List<SelectListItem> Answers { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem("Test1", "Test1") };
```

The binding works properly when I pass data on page loading, but the list is empty when I submit my form.

Here is HTML code before pressing Submit button:

```html
<select id="answersList" multiple="multiple" data-val="true" name="Answers">
   <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
   <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
   <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

and the screenshot from IDE:
[image]

As you can see, the list in the code is empty. How can I pass the items a user added to the back-end?

The other bind properties have the correct data. So, the problem is on this list only.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are POST'ing the form?

Comment: the knowledge behind this issue is the `<select>` element will have its value post to the server in a form of an array of the item values. Usually that will be an array of strings or array of integers. So your model must have a corresponding bound property of `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<int>`. The property name must match with the name of `<select>` (in the simplest case, not accounting for prefix or custom property name with `BindAttribute` ...)

Comment: It seems that I don't POST the options. At least I can't see them in the Form Data section. But what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture the request and check the actual data that you post in browser F12 developer tool Network tab, you would find it looks like below.

[image]

Which can not be bound to `List<SelectListItem>` type property `Answers`.

> How can I pass the items a user added to the back-end?

To achieve your requirement, you can try to modify the code like below.

*Define a `List<string>` type property `SelectedAnswers` in PageModel class*

```
public List<SelectListItem> Answers { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem("Test1", "Test1") };
[BindProperty]
public List<string> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
```

*Update select tag helper with `asp-for="SelectedAnswers"`*

```
<form method="post">
    <select asp-for="SelectedAnswers" asp-items="Model.Answers" multiple="multiple"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Test Result

[image]

***Update:***

> I didn't select any options from the select list, so I didn't get any items. However, I don't want to ask a user to select options; I want to post all of them. Is there a simple way to do it, or should I use javascript code to select all items before submitting?

You can try to [set all SelectListItem to selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectListItem__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) by default while you add new SelectListItem to `List<SelectListItem> Answers`, like below.

```
//...
Answers.Add(new SelectListItem("Test2", "Test2", true));
Answers.Add(new SelectListItem("Test3", "Test3", true));
//...
```

Besides, as you mentioned, you can also achieve same to set all items/options to selected using JavaScript before submitting the form.

```
$("form").first().submit(function () {
    $('#myList option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: It seems that I don't POST the options. At least I can't see them in the Form Data section. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I can't see them in the Form Data section` Hi @GrigoryZhadko, please check if you add select tag helper in a `<form>`.

Comment: Do you mean inside the `<form>`? If so, then yes, I added my `<select>` inside it.
The weird thing is that I have a dropdown select near and it works as expected: `<select class="form-control" asp-for="Input.QuestionType" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(QuestionType))"></select>`

Comment: So, I believe there is something with binding

Comment: Hi @GrigoryZhadko, please use f12 developer tool to check and share the actual html source code of "Answers" dropdown, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: I think I found the cause of the issue. I didn't select any options from the `select` list, so I didn't get any items. However, I don't want to ask a user to select options; I want to post all of them. Is there a simple way to do it, or should I use javascript code to select all items before submitting?

Comment: `Is there a simple way to do it, or should I use javascript code to select all items before submitting?` Hi @GrigoryZhadko, please check my new update.

Comment: Hi @GrigoryZhadko, any updates about this case? Does it help achieve the requirement by making all SelectListItem(s) selected in default.

Comment: Hi @Fei Han. Sorry, I thought that I answered you, but I didn't. First of all, I wanted to thank you because your answer helped me to handle the issue. Secondly, could you please add javascript (or jquery) code to your answer so that it can be fully completed and I can mark it as a correct one? You can use my code, for example:  ```$('#myForm').submit(function (){
 $('#myList option').prop('selected', true);
})```

Comment: `could you please add javascript (or jquery) code to your answer so that it can be fully completed and I can mark it as a correct one?` Hi @GrigoryZhadko, have  updated with jquery code in my above reply.